# Get the average rating in flask blog, SQL, Python

Tags: python, sql, flask, average

I'm creating a Flask Blog using SQL-alchemy and Python. The blog is a blog for recipes where the users can rate the recipes. I get all the ratings to appear BUT I also want to get the average rating. I've tried this so far but I can't get it to work...

In my HTML:

```
 <div id="recipe" class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Average Rating: </strong>{{ post.critic_avg }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

In my routes file:

```
@app.route("/recipes/<int:recipe_id>")
def recipe(recipe_id):
    recipe = Recipe.query.get_or_404(recipe_id)
    form = RatingForm()
    critic_avg = db.session.query(func.avg(Rating.rating)).all()
    return render_template('recipe_page.html', title=recipe.title, post=recipe, form=form, critic_avg=critic_avg)
```

In my models:

```
class Rating(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    rating = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    user = db.relationship(User, backref=db.backref('ratings', lazy=True))
    recipe_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('recipe.id'), nullable=False)
    recipe = db.relationship(Recipe, backref=db.backref('ratings', lazy=True))
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Rating (id='{self.id}', rating='{self.rating}', user_id='{self.user_id}', recipe_id='{self.recipe_id}')>"
```

Maybe I'm doing it totaly wrong, would be very happy for some guidance :)

Comment: Is the problem SQL related? I see no SQL above.

Comment: Yes, we are doing a FlaskBlog using SQL and Python :)

Comment: If you need SQL assistance, we need to see sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, and also the current query attempt. I.e. [mcve].

Comment: what is the result of `critic_avg = db.session.query(func.avg(Rating.rating)).all()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things,
First, `all()` will return list with single item in it, in such case you can use `scalar()` that will give you single value

```py
critic_avg = db.session.query(func.avg(Rating.rating)).scalar() or 0
```

and in jinja you are trying to access `critic_avg` using `post.critic_avg` while it is not available using post, you are passing it to jinja as `critic_avg` so, in jinja you can access it directly

```html
<li class="list-group-item"><strong>Average Rating: </strong>{{ critic_avg }}</li>
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.scalar